# How to overide other module method in Node

Tags: node.js

module1.js

```
// here how can i overide the module2 someMethod()
```

module2.js

```
exports.someMethod=function() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('./module2').someMethod = function myOwnMethod () {
  // Not too hard was it?
};
```